# Help me find the values of $x\in (0,\infty)$ for which the inequality $4\sqrt{x}>5-\frac{1}{x^2}$ hold?

Tags: calculus, inequality

> For which values of $x\in (0,\infty)$ does the inequality
>   $4\sqrt{x}>5-\frac{1}{x^2}$ hold? You must use some relevant
>   properties of differentiable functions

**My Approach**

First from my mind I tried to guess, and my guess says that it holds for $x>1$, because obviously:

$4\sqrt{x}=5-\frac{1}{x^2}$ at $x=1$

$4\sqrt{x}<5-\frac{1}{x^2}$ at $x=0$

and for negative $x$, we are dealing with imaginary numbers so we can't decide if an imaginary number is greater or less than a real number.

---

Then I started solving it, to write it in a proper way:

$$4\sqrt{x}>5-\frac{1}{x^2}$$

$$4x^2\sqrt{x}>5x^2-1$$

Squaring gives:

$$16x^5>25x^4-10x^2+1$$

Now, obviously this is a 5th power equation, I do not know how to solve this. However, from my guess I can clearly see $x=1$ is a critical point.

**But here's what makes me suspicious about my method**:

The question says use some relevant properties of differentiable functions. **How do I use those?**

Comment: That last inequality looks good. Bring everything to one side to create a zero on the other. You already found a zero by inspection (no reason to be suspicious), so through factor division, you can take that "out" Still leaves you with a fourth degree polynomial. Rational zero theorem may be an option. Remember the domain of your given problem though

Comment: See that $4\sqrt{x}>5-\frac{1}{x^2} \iff 4\sqrt{x}+\frac{1}{x^2} > 5$ which is just the AM-GM inequality with $\{\sqrt{x},\sqrt{x},\sqrt{x},\sqrt{x},x^{-2}\}$ :-) so it holds for all $x > 0$.

Comment: $a\geqslant b$ doesn't imply that $a^2 \geqslant b^2$. For example, $2 \geqslant -5$ but $2^2 < (-5)^2$.

Comment: @r9m but they say: use some differentiable function properties

Comment: @Éric you are right. Didn't think of that

Comment: @r9m But it DOESNT HOLD FOR X=1, so how can we say x>0?

Comment: @M.S.E You can take $f(x) = 4\sqrt{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}-5$ and as you have noticed $f(1) = 0$ indeed! So it remains to show $f$ is increasing in $(1,\infty)$ and decreasing in $(0,1)$ intervals :)

Comment: @r9m so the final answer would be x>1? 

Comment: @M.S.E $(0,1) \cup (1,\infty)$ .. see the [W|A](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bx%5E2%7D%2B4%5Csqrt%7Bx%7D+-+5) output.

Comment: @r9m Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f$ the function defined on $(0,+\infty)$ by
$$
  f(x) = 4\sqrt{x} - 5 + \frac{1}{x^2}.
$$
It is differentiable: for all real $x>0$, we have
$$
  f'(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{x}} - \frac{2}{x^3} = \frac{2(x^{5/2}-1)}{x^3}.
$$
The function $x\mapsto x^{5/2}-1$ is strictly increasing on $(0,+\infty)$ and is zero at $1$. Moreover $x^3 > 0$ on $(0,+\infty)$. Therefore the derivative $f'$
is negative on $(0,1)$ and positive on $(1,+\infty)$. In other words, the function $f$ is strictly decreasing on $(0,1]$ and is strictly increasing on $[1,+\infty)$
with $f(1) = 0$. We conclude that the set of solutions of the inequality $f(x) > 0$, or equivalently
$$
  4\sqrt{x} > 5 - 1/x^2 \quad (x>0),
$$
is $(0,1)\cup (1,+\infty)$.